# Carriage Return not working in SSH execute command on remote

Tags: ssh

The output without Carriage Return when I use ssh to execute a remote command. sometimes the output is too much. for example, the terminal print download progress updates each line when I execute `ssh server -- "docker compose up -d --build"`. Is there any way to make the output the same as I execute it in the remote server terminal?

Comment: Does it act any better if you use `ssh -t`?

Comment: oh, it's work, thanks a lot. @DopeGhoti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `docker` application may be checking upon its invocation whether it is being run in a terminal, and altering its output based upon its findings.

The `-t` argument for `ssh` tells the client to open a remote terminal even if it doesn't think one is needed (which it often will presume when invoked to run a non-interactive environment, as is the case in your question).  You may find this invocation changes `docker`'s output to your liking:

```
$ ssh -t server -- "docker compose up -d --build"
```